# Fatal error: Class 'Silex' not found

Tags: php, silex, phar

I try silex for building my application. When I try to test my first application, I get an error like this:

> Fatal error: Class 'Silex' not found in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/silex/try.php on line 5

and this is my code :

```
<?php
  #require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar';  
  require_once 'phar://'.__DIR__.'/silex.phar/vendor/.composer/autoload.php';  
  #require_once 'phar://'.__DIR__.'/silex.phar/autoload.php';  
  $app= new Silex/Application();  
  $app->get('hello/{name}',function($name) use($app){  
     return 'Hello ' .$app->escape($name);  
  });  
  $app['debug'] == true;  
  $app->run();  
?>
```

I've searched for my error in a search engine and I have some suggestions like to add this code in php.ini:

```
extension=phar.so  
phar.readonly = Off  
phar.require_hash = Off  
detect_unicode = Off
```

But I still get the same error when I test in a web browser. What's your suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially it looks like your line:

```
$app= new Silex/Application();
```

Should actually read (note the backslash):

```
$app= new Silex\Application();
```

`\` is the namespace separator, what your code is doing is is running `new Silex` then dividing that by `Application()`, and as `class Silex` does not exist, compilation fails.

Hopefully that solves the problem!

**Also:**

I think the line `$app['debug'] == true;` should be `$app['debug'] = true;` (single equals) - double equals is an equality test, single equals is assignment.